# Moving SQL Server database to shared hosting using backup

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio-2010, shared-hosting

I need to move my SQL Server database to shared hosting. Is there a tool there that allows me to import a database backup file? I'm stuck with actually making `.bak` file.

Its suggested that I use SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), I tried downloading it from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=7593), but failed to install.

I found I could run a query like

```
BACKUP DATABASE mydbname TO disk = 'd:\bak'
```

but can't figure out where I do this in VS 2010.

I'm stuck on this lame problem, please give me a hint.

Comment: You are really trying to do this from a program just beacuse you failed to install SQL Server Management Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved: I found this detailed tutorial on how to install SSMS [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2011/02/18/step-by-step-installing-sql-server-management-studio-2008-express-after-visual-studio-2010.aspx).

Then I used following query to make backup:

```
 BACKUP DATABASE mydbname TO disk = 'd:\bak'
```

Answer (score 2):

This little utility could be your solution, it's free for any manually backups.

[SQLBackupAndFTP](http://sqlbackupandftp.com/)

However, remember that a SQLServer backup could be restored only on the same or subsequent versions of SQLServer

Comment: Thanks for this, but I have actually found other method.